# Using Boost random infrastructure but how to easily replace a component (say the underlying generator)?

Tags: c++, boost, random, replace, prng

My use case is, say, classroom use.

The Boost random infrastructure is already there and I try to avoid the NIH syndrom. But let's say, I want to

1- study the properties (ok, say flaws) of various PRNGs and their impact on say the generation of normal (or other distribution) variates. How to do that and still retain the other Boost features of generating a whole bunch of distributions?

2- use a Boot (say Mersenne Twister) generator and test various ways of generating other distributions (say the normal one).

Is there an easy and general way to do that kind of drop-in replacement of any of Boost random infrastructure component and still be able to use the rest?

Answer (score 0):

The basic source of randomness in Boost.Random is called a "generator".
There are [several provided in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.generators), but I see no reason that you cannot use your own instead.

The examples in the boost docs show how to create a generator object, and then passing it to a distribution to get a series of numbers.

*-- Later --*

Here's a basic generator I whipped up (based on rand48):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/random.hpp>

class my_rand {
public:
//  types
    typedef boost::uint32_t result_type;

//  construct/copy/destruct
    my_rand () : next_ ( 0 ) {}
    explicit my_rand( result_type x ) : next_ ( x ) {}

//  public static functions
    static uint32_t min() { return 0; }
    static uint32_t max() { return 10; }

    // public member functions
    void seed() { next_ = 0; }
    void seed(result_type x) { next_ = x; }
//  template<typename It> void seed(It &, It);
//  template<typename SeedSeq> void seed(SeedSeq &);
    uint32_t operator()() {
        if ( ++next_ == max ())
            next_ = min ();
        return next_;
        }

    void discard(boost::uintmax_t) {}
//  template<typename Iter> void generate(Iter, Iter);

    friend bool operator==(const my_rand & x, const my_rand &y);
    friend bool operator!=(const my_rand & x, const my_rand &y);
    // public data members
    static const bool has_fixed_range;
private:
    result_type next_;
};

bool operator==(const my_rand & x, const my_rand &y) { return x.next_ == y.next_; }
bool operator!=(const my_rand & x, const my_rand &y) { return x.next_ != y.next_; }
const bool my_rand::has_fixed_range = true;

int main ( int, char ** ) {
//  boost::random::mt19937 rng;
    my_rand rng;
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> six(1,6);

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
        std::cout << six(rng) << std::endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

Obviously, the output is not random.
But it does interoperate with the Boost.Random infrastructure.

Comment: I know there are several provided in Boost. But how would I provide one (from scratch) that still can use Boost's distribution mappings ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any documentation about writing your own generators for Boost.Random, so I guess that I would start with one of the provided ones and try to match the interface.